# Data structure to handle array with changing indices

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have an array with space for say 8 elements. I want to fill this array with numbers 8,7,...,1 at indices indicated by the following array:

```
7 4 4 2 1 2 0 0
```

You must've notices that some indices are repeating. This is so because these **numbers indicate indices for the remaining array**.

I will guide you through the steps of array filling so you get the idea :

**Initial Array**(*with indices*)

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

**Step 1**

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 -
```

**Step 2**

```
_ _ _ _ 7 _ _ 8
0 1 2 3 - 4 5 -
```

Notice how the indices got updated as I filled in "7", so that I can fill "6" at index 4 too, as index 4 is a new position.

**Step 3**

```
_ _ _ _ 7 6 _ 8
0 1 2 3 - - 4 -
```

**Step 4**

```
_ _ 5 _ 7 6 _ 8
0 1 - 2 - - 3 -
```

**Step 5**

```
_ 4 5 _ 7 6 _ 8
0 - - 1 - - 2 -
```

**Step 6**

```
_ 4 5 _ 7 6 3 8
0 - - 1 - - - -
```

**Step 7**

```
2 4 5 _ 7 6 3 8
- - - 0 - - - -
```

and "1" can be filled at the last place.

I have solved the problem directly scanning the array for the ith empty place if I have to fill at index i. It is O(n^2). I need better.

**Question:** Is there a data structure that can optimize the above algorithm? Or can the algorithm itself be improved?

**NOTE:** I have tried using BIT, but failed.

Comment: Can you give some background on how this data structure will be used?  If we understand its purpose better, we can probably give better advice (and avoid an XY problem)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I need the structure to particularly store the "index" of a position in the array. e.g. in step 7, the index for position 4 is 0, and so on.

The X: I am trying to solve this online judge problem and I have boiled down to this algorithm. http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/FINDPERM

Comment: @Cheeku If this is an ongoing competition I don't really feel comfortable providing a major hint.

Comment: @Nabla This is just an archive of problems, not an ongoing competition. The particular problem is from June 2005.
If it were ongoing, I don't really feel comfortable asking for a major hint either. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store all initial indices in a binary search tree. Also store along with each node the number of total children (all deeper levels).

As soon as you inserted one element in the array, remove its index from the tree in O(log n). At the same time update the child counts.

For the next insert in the array at index `i` in "new indices" you need to find the `i`th element in ordering of the search tree which will give you the position in "original" indices. Since the number of childs at each node can be queried, this can be done in O(log n) as well.

So the full average- and worst-case complexity is O(n log n).

Comment: Seems legit! But let me give it a shot!

Comment: @Cheeku Additional point: The search tree will never grow, so it doesn't need to be balanced or anything (except initially).

Answer (score 1):

If you accept to use additional O(n) memory you may do this:

- Create a helper array, which at index i stores the index of i'th free place in the original data array. So, if your original array have indexes 0 - 7 and places indexed 1, 3, 5 are free, then your helper array would look like: [1, 3, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], where -1 indicates there is no such amount of free space in the original array.
- In order to insert an element at i'th free position in the data array you do this:

> ```
>     int j = helperArray[i];
>     if (j > -1){
>         dataArray[j] = itemYouWantToInsert;
>         while (i < helperArray.size() - 1){
>               helperArray[i] = helperArray[i+1];
>               i++;
>           }
>           helperArray[i] = -1;
>     }
>     else
>         cout<<"There are less free places in the dataArray.";
> ```

The insertion time is O(k) then, where k = (n - i). So pesimistic time of insertion is O(n), but optimistic one is O(1). isFree() is just an example method, as I do not know how do you recogize "empty space" in the dataArray.

Comment: This is the same algorithm the questioner proposed, only reversed in the sense that you remove indicies as you go along, while the questioner adds them. The algorithm has worst-case and average-case time complexity O(n^2) for inserts of all indices. Best-case however is O(n).